# Two accepted answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, accepted-answer

[This question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/122955/34339) has two [accepted](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/122962/34339) [answers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/122963/34339). How is that possible?

[image]

Comment: Interesting... if I had to guess it probably had an accepted answer from where it was migrated from, and that accepted answer didn't get cleared after migration.  I asked the overlords about this.

Comment: Hm. I wonder if it's related to [this issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147004/167443).

Comment: The [timeline](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/122955/timeline) shows both accepts and then shows one of them being unaccepted during the migration.

Comment: similar question at MSO: [Two accepted answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127792/165773)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few bits of denormalized data that determine whether a given answer is "accepted": the question knows of *an* accepted answer, each answer knows if it is accepted, and there are the actual "accept" votes as well. Occasionally, these can get out of sync with one another. That happened here (it shouldn't happen anymore, but this is an old question with a lot of history behind it).

Now there are *no* accepted answers on that question, which seems appropriate given there's no owner either.